# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question is a question about a Windows Server configuration issue:

[Configure IIS Web Site for alternate Port and receive Access Permission error](https://serverfault.com/questions/439379/tcp-port-permissions)

For some reason it was moved to Stack Overflow even though it has nothing to do with programming. On the same day it was closed as "off topic" by several people on Server Fault.

On Stack Overflow it survived for a few days with me repeatedly asking to move it back to Server Fault since it was not a programming question.

Then it was closed on Stack Overflow too, for being "off topic" (which I totally agree with).

I totally don't see why a question about a TCP port issue affecting IIS on Windows Server should be "off topic" on Server Fault.

And what's worse, I still have that problem and could really need an answer rather than a discussion about why I am not allowed to have the problem. Problems with IIS and TCP on a Windows Server ought to be on topic on Server Fault!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what happened there...
I can only assume all those people didn't actually read the Question.

Comment: Thanks! At least I now know that I haven't gone completely insane. For a while it seemed like I was the only person on earth who did not think that the question was completely off topic.

Comment: Your edits confused the issue a bit. MQSeries has the same problems as IIS, since the port appears in-use all the time (and cannot be used by either IIS or MQ). I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: Oops, thank you for fixing that... I get a bit heavy handed in cleaning up questions sometimes.